# ASP.NET C# GridView Losing Search Options When Paging or Sorting

Tags: c#, asp.net, sorting, gridview, paging

I have been trying to fix this for a good portion of the day with research and I have not been able to find an answer that works with my current code.  I have set up a GridView that is controlled by three drop down lists and a textbox.  As these change this builds the WHERE part of my SQL Statement so I can pull only the data that I want.

My concern is that most of these pull thousands of data points so I would like to use the option to page through the GridView and/or Sort it by the columns.

The Page and Sort worked initially but now I only get a blank GridView every time I try to Page or Sort now.

The ASPX file:

```
<%@ Page Language="C#" AutoEventWireup="true" CodeBehind="Default.aspx.cs" Inherits="TestAsset.Default" %>

<!DOCTYPE html>

<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head runat="server">
    <title></title>
</head>
<body>
    <form id="form1" runat="server">
        <hr />
    <div>
        <a href="Upload.aspx">Manual Assets</a>
    </div>
        <hr />
    <div>
        <asp:DropDownList ID="ddlSource" runat="server" AutoPostBack="true" Width="100px" OnSelectedIndexChanged="ddlSource_SelectedIndexChanged">
            /* Removed to Protect the Innocent */
        </asp:DropDownList>
        <asp:DropDownList ID="ddlAssetType" runat="server" AutoPostBack="true" Width="150px" OnSelectedIndexChanged="ddl_SelectedIndexChanged">
            <asp:ListItem Selected="True" Text="ALL" Value="0" />
        </asp:DropDownList>
        <asp:TextBox ID="tbAsset" runat="server" AutoPostBack="false" Width="500px" OnTextChanged="ddl_SelectedIndexChanged" />
        <asp:DropDownList ID="ddlSSP" runat="server" AutoPostBack="true" Width="250px" OnSelectedIndexChanged="ddl_SelectedIndexChanged">
            <asp:ListItem Selected="True" Text="ALL" Value="0" />
        </asp:DropDownList>
    </div>
        <hr />
    <div>
        <asp:GridView ID="gvAllAssets" runat="server" AllowPaging="True" AllowSorting="True" AutoGenerateColumns="False" CellPadding="4" ForeColor="#333333" GridLines="Vertical" PageSize="25" OnPageIndexChanging="gvAllAssets_PageIndexChanging" OnSorting="gvAllAssets_Sorting">
            <AlternatingRowStyle BackColor="White" ForeColor="#284775" />
            <EditRowStyle BackColor="#999999" />
            <EmptyDataTemplate>No Data Found</EmptyDataTemplate>
            <FooterStyle BackColor="#5D7B9D" Font-Bold="True" ForeColor="White" />
            <HeaderStyle BackColor="#5D7B9D" Font-Bold="True" ForeColor="White" />
            <PagerStyle BackColor="#284775" ForeColor="White" HorizontalAlign="Center" />
            <RowStyle BackColor="#F7F6F3" ForeColor="#333333" />
            <SelectedRowStyle BackColor="#E2DED6" Font-Bold="True" ForeColor="#333333" />
            <SortedAscendingCellStyle BackColor="#E9E7E2" />
            <SortedAscendingHeaderStyle BackColor="#506C8C" />
            <SortedDescendingCellStyle BackColor="#FFFDF8" />
            <SortedDescendingHeaderStyle BackColor="#6F8DAE" />
            <Columns>
                <asp:BoundField DataField="SOURCENAME" HeaderText="Source" InsertVisible="false" ReadOnly="true" SortExpression="SOURCENAME">
                    <ItemStyle Width="100px" Wrap="false" />
                </asp:BoundField>
                <asp:BoundField DataField="ASSETNAME" HeaderText="Asset Type" InsertVisible="false" ReadOnly="true" SortExpression="ASSETNAME">
                    <ItemStyle Width="150px" Wrap="false" />
                </asp:BoundField>
                <asp:BoundField DataField="ASSET" HeaderText="Asset" InsertVisible="false" ReadOnly="true" SortExpression="ASSET">
                    <ItemStyle Width="500px" Wrap="false" />
                </asp:BoundField>
                <asp:BoundField DataField="SSP" HeaderText="System Security Plan" InsertVisible="false" ReadOnly="true" SortExpression="SSP">
                    <ItemStyle Width="250px" Wrap="false" />
                </asp:BoundField>
                <asp:BoundField DataField="LAST_UPDATED" HeaderText="Last Updated" InsertVisible="false" ReadOnly="true" SortExpression="LAST_UPDATED">
                    <ItemStyle Width="250px" Wrap="false" />
                </asp:BoundField>
            </Columns>
        </asp:GridView>

        <asp:SqlDataSource ID="dsAllAssets" runat="server" ConnectionString="<%$ ConnectionStrings:TestAssetConnectionString %>" />
    </div>
        <hr />
    <div>
        <asp:Label ID="lblSQLStatement" runat="server" />
    </div>
        <hr />
    </form>
</body>
</html>
```

The Code Behind File:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Configuration;
using System.Data;
using System.Data.SqlClient;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;
using System.Web.UI;
using System.Web.UI.WebControls;

namespace TestAsset
{
public partial class Default : System.Web.UI.Page
{
    private string strWhere = String.Empty;

    protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (!IsPostBack)
        {
            ddlSource_SelectedIndexChanged(this, EventArgs.Empty);
        }
    }

    protected void ddlSource_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        strWhere = String.Empty;

        ddl_SelectedIndexChanged(sender, e);

        Update_DropdownLists(ddlAssetType, "ASSETID", "ASSETNAME");
        Update_DropdownLists(ddlSSP, "DENSE_RANK() OVER (ORDER BY SSP) AS Row", "SSP");
    }

    protected void ddl_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        strWhere = String.Empty;

        if (ddlSource.SelectedValue != "0")
        {
            if (strWhere == String.Empty)
            {
                strWhere = "WHERE SDBs.SOURCE = " + ddlSource.SelectedValue;
            }
            else
            {
                strWhere = strWhere + " AND SDBs.SOURCE = " + ddlSource.SelectedValue;
            }
        }

        if (ddlAssetType.SelectedValue != "0")
        {
            if (strWhere == String.Empty)
            {
                strWhere = "WHERE Assets.ASSET_TYPE = " + ddlAssetType.SelectedValue;
            }
            else
            {
                strWhere = strWhere + " AND Assets.ASSET_TYPE = " + ddlAssetType.SelectedValue;
            }
        }

        if (tbAsset.Text != "")
        {
            if (strWhere == String.Empty)
            {
                strWhere = "WHERE Assets.ASSET LIKE '%" + tbAsset.Text + "%'";
            }
            else
            {
                strWhere = strWhere + " AND Assets.ASSET LIKE '%" + tbAsset.Text + "%'";
            }
        }

        if (ddlSSP.SelectedValue != "0")
        {
            if (strWhere == String.Empty)
            {
                strWhere = "WHERE Assets.SSP = '" + ddlSSP.SelectedItem + "'";
            }
            else
            {
                strWhere = strWhere + " AND Assets.SSP = '" + ddlSSP.SelectedItem + "'";
            }
        }

        Update_GridView();
    }

    protected void Update_GridView()
    {
        string selectStatement =
            "SELECT " +
                "SDBNames.SOURCENAME AS 'SOURCENAME', " +
                "AssetNames.ASSETNAME AS 'ASSETNAME', " +
                "Assets.ASSET AS 'ASSET', " +
                "Assets.SSP AS 'SSP', " +
                "SDBs.LAST_UPDATED AS 'LAST_UPDATED' " +
            "FROM " +
                "Assets " +
            "INNER JOIN AssetNames " +
                "ON Assets.ASSET_TYPE = AssetNames.ASSETID " +
            "INNER JOIN SDBs " +
                "ON Assets.SDBID = SDBs.ID " +
            "INNER JOIN SDBNames " +
                "ON SDBs.SOURCE = SDBNames.SOURCEID " +
            strWhere + " ;";

        lblSQLStatement.Text = selectStatement;

        dsAllAssets.SelectCommand = selectStatement;
        DataView dv = (DataView)dsAllAssets.Select(DataSourceSelectArguments.Empty);
        DataTable dt = dv.ToTable();

        dsAllAssets.DataBind();

        if (dt.Rows.Count > 0)
        {
            gvAllAssets.DataSourceID = "dsAllAssets";
            gvAllAssets.DataBind();
        }
        else
        {
            gvAllAssets.DataSourceID = "";
            ShowNoResultFound(dt, gvAllAssets);
            gvAllAssets.Rows[0].Cells[0].Width = 1250;
        }
    }

    protected void Update_DropdownLists(DropDownList ddl, string valueField, string textField)
    {
        string modifiedValue;

        if (valueField.Contains(" AS "))
        {
            modifiedValue = valueField.Split(' ').Last();
        }
        else
        {
            modifiedValue = valueField;
        }

        string strSSPCommand = "" +
            "SELECT DISTINCT " +
                valueField + ", " +
                textField + " " +
            "FROM " +
                "Assets " +
            "INNER JOIN AssetNames " +
                "ON Assets.ASSET_TYPE = AssetNames.ASSETID " +
            "INNER JOIN SDBs " +
                "ON Assets.SDBID = SDBs.ID " +
            "INNER JOIN SDBNames " +
                "ON SDBs.SOURCE = SDBNames.SOURCEID " +
            strWhere + " " +
            "ORDER BY " + modifiedValue + " ;";

        SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["TestAssetConnectionString"].ConnectionString);
        SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(strSSPCommand, con);
        SqlDataAdapter da = new SqlDataAdapter(cmd);
        DataTable dt = new DataTable();
        da.Fill(dt);

        ddl.DataValueField = modifiedValue;
        ddl.DataTextField = textField;
        ddl.DataSource = dt;
        ddl.DataBind();
        ddl.Items.Insert(0, new ListItem("ALL", "0"));
    }

    protected void ShowNoResultFound(DataTable source, GridView target)
    {
        source.Rows.Add(source.NewRow());

        target.DataSource = source;
        target.DataBind();

        int columnsCount = target.Columns.Count;
        target.Rows[0].Cells.Clear();
        target.Rows[0].Cells.Add(new TableCell());

        target.Rows[0].Cells[0].ColumnSpan = columnsCount;
        target.Rows[0].Cells[0].ForeColor = System.Drawing.Color.Red;
        target.Rows[0].Cells[0].Font.Bold = true;
        target.Rows[0].Cells[0].HorizontalAlign = HorizontalAlign.Center;
        target.Rows[0].Cells[0].Text = "NO RESULTS FOUND!";
    }

    protected void gvAllAssets_PageIndexChanging(object sender, GridViewPageEventArgs e)
    {
        gvAllAssets.PageIndex = e.NewPageIndex;
        gvAllAssets.DataBind();
    }

    protected void gvAllAssets_Sorting(object sender, GridViewSortEventArgs e)
    {
        gvAllAssets.Sort(e.SortExpression, e.SortDirection);
        gvAllAssets.DataBind();
    }


}
}
```

---

**EDIT 04/11/2016**

---

I admit it now, I am not the best at ASP.net but was told I needed to just make 'something' to show what we have in the database.  Got little overzealous with the search options and fought it for awhile to get it to work.  Then I just went ahead and restored a backup copy of my code and it worked with searching, paging, and sorting again... as I had the DataSourceID set in the HTML code again, which I took out initially so it would show something interesting if there was no data shown.  So just going to leave it at there for now and move on!

Answer (score 0):

First thing to try is this, use the GridView's `.DataSource` property and not `.DataSourceID`.  Providing the `DataSourceID` causes certain automated binding operations to occur during the page lifecycle.  Since you're trying to manage the databinding yourself via specific input events you don't want additional databinds to be called.

Also - you really are making things much harder for yourself.  Stored procedures work far better when you are trying to reduce a data set with user inputs. Far better to utilize the full capability of the SqlDataSource to accept WebControls as input parameters, e.g.:

```
    <asp:SqlDataSource ID="dsAllAssets" runat="server" ConnectionString="<%$ ConnectionStrings:TestAssetConnectionString %>" 
        SelectCommand="sp_SomeProcedureYouCreate" 
        SelectCommandType="StoredProcedure">
      <SelectParameters>
        <asp:ControlParameter Name="sp_var_1" ControlID="ddlAssetType" PropertyName="SelectedValue" Type="Int32" />
        <asp:ControlParameter Name="sp_var_2" ControlID="tbAsset" PropertyName="Text" Type="String" />
        <asp:ControlParameter Name="sp_var_3" ControlID="ddlSSP" PropertyName="SelectedValue" Type="Int32" />
      </SelectParameters>
    </asp:SqlDataSource>
```

In this way you can set this:

```
    <asp:GridView ID="gvAllAssets" runat="server" DataSourceID="dsAllAssets" ... />
```

Set the input `DropDownList` and `TextBox` controls to postback on change to rebind.  Or set up a button to postback only once after the user makes his/her input selections

Comment: Thank you for the suggestions!  I am looking into modifying my code to see if it runs more efficiently with a StoredProcedure though I am having to do some research on how to handle the fact that there are possibly 24 combinations with the WHERE clause.  This is because with three drop down lists and one text box it is possible that user may select none of them, one of them, two of them, three of them, or all four.

Comment: Well that is a design consideration.  But you can likewise set up any number of `SqlDatasource`s to use the same input controls but provide different stored procedures for each and then set the GridView `DataSourceID` to the appropriate source.  Also keep in mind that the `Visibility` property on databound controls plays into databinding operations.  Invisible controls won't get databound even if the `DataSourceID` is set